# What is the best way to call pictureBox1 on Form1 from a number of classes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two classes. And a pictureBox1 on form1.
In the first class i'm using the pictureBox1 like this:

On top of class:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1;
```

Then in the class constructor:

```
InitializeTest(pb1);
```

And inside InitializeTest i'm using the pb1.

And in Form1:

```
DopplerRadar dr = new DopplerRadar();
dr.pb1 = pictureBox1;
dr.Init();
```

Now i have another class:

```
class GeneratePoints
    {
        private Bitmap backImage;
        public Color backImagecolor;
        public Bitmap imageWithPoints;
        public int numberOfPoints;
        public bool randomPoints;
        public bool randomColors;

        private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        private Random r = new Random();

        private void Init()
        {
            backImage = new Bitmap(pb1.Width, pb1.Height);
```

And also here in this class i want to use the pictureBox1 in form1.
I can declare in this class also the pb1:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1;
```

The question is if there is a better way to do it ?
And if i will want to use the both classes sometime in another project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods

### Push

You can pass a reference to the PictureBox into the function or method that is going to use it.  The function can then do the drawing.

For example, if your `Generatepoints` class needs the ability to draw its points onto the PictureBox, define a method that looks like this:

```
class GeneratePoints 
{
    ...
    public void Draw(PictureBox pictureBox)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox.Handle))
        {
            foreach (var p in points)
            {
                //Draw the point
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Pull

This approach is less intuitive but much more common.

Create an event handler for the PictureBox's [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event.  In the handler, go out and grab the current instance of the `GeneratePoints` class and use its data to draw the points.

The advantage of this method is that it will only run when the picture box needs to be painted; it won't run if the picturebox is contained on a form that is hidden (e.g. by another window that is on top of it).